# Deduplicating lines in large file fails with sort and uniq

Tags: bash, sorting, duplicates, large-files

I have a large file which consists of one line of JSON per line for 1563888 lines. To deduplicate the lines among this file I have been using the shell one-liner `sort myfile.json | uniq -u`.

For smaller files this approach worked and `sort myfile.json | uniq -u | wc -l` was larger than 0. Due to the file size now running `sort myfile.json | uniq -u | wc -l` produces 0 lines while if I use `head -n500000 myfile.json | sort | uniq -u | wc -l` works.

Is there an easy way for bash to handle such large files? Or is there a clean way to chunk the file up? I was using bash initially instead of Python as it seemed like an easier way to quickly verify things though now I am thinking about moving this task back to Python.

Comment: I think you want `split` https://www.linuxtechi.com/split-command-examples-for-linux-unix/

Comment: Should be fine. Are you sure you're not getting any errors? Do any of the programs exit with nonzero status?

Comment: `Due to the file size` `produces 0 lines` Can't be. This is hard to believe. It should work very, very long or at least should throw an error (most probably "Out of memory"). Btw. `sort -u` is shorter (thus less memory consuming) then `sort | uniq -u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Kamil Cuk, let's try this solution:

```
sort -u myfile.json
```

Is the file really JSON?  Sorting a JSON file can lead to dubious results.  You may also try split'ing the file as suggested by Mark Setchell.  You can then sort each split file, and sort the results.  All  sorts should be done with `sort -u`.

Please provide some sample from myfile.json if indeed it is a JSON file.  Let's here about your results when you just use `sort -u`.

Comment: The file is ja son newline file. `sort -u myfile.json` returns a non zero result while `sort myfile.json | uniq -u ` returns 0 lines. Pretty interesting behaviour, I wonder why `sort -u` and `sort | uniq -u` behave so differently here.